# Problems passing value from Google Play URL to app via INSTALL_REFERRER Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I'm having problems passing `transaction_id` from google play URL after app is installed.

The URL looks something like this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bouncing.mate.bouncer&transaction_id=12345

When app is installed using this url, I try to retrieve `transaction_id` value from `INSTALL_REFERRER` Intent. To do this, I declared a receiver in my manifest:

```
<!-- The Google Play com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER Intent is broadcast when an app is installed from the Google Play Store.
This broadcast receiver listens for that Intent, passing the data required for app install tracking. -->

<receiver
    android:name=".data.tracking.AppInstallReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My receiver class looks like this:

```
public class AppInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.hasExtra("transaction_id")) {
            // Intent has transaction id extra, start Service that will handle tracking
            context.startService(AppInstallService.getIntent(context, intent.getStringExtra("transaction_id")));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't think my service is started ever... I'm not sure if "transaction_id" parameter can be passed this way? In all examples I've seen so far, the "refferer" key is used.
    e.g. :

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String referrerString = extras.getString("referrer");
```

Service was tested using:
`adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER --es "transaction_id" "1234567"` and it should work fine, but receiving the intent upon installation is something I can't test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only query param allowed is "referrer"

You can put a bunch of things into the referrer, and they must be url-encoded, for example if you pass:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example&referrer=utm_source%3Dwebsite%26utm_medium%3Dmoweb%26utm_campaign%3Dsmartbanner then google will call your broadcast receiver with

receiver = "utm_source=website&utm_medium=moweb&utm_campaign=smartbanner"